# Flexdashboard doesn't display text in one of the tabs, but works perfect as .html file

Tags: html, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Rmarkdown after knit the Flexdashboard `.doc` doesn't display the content in a tab, but it will display the output from `.html` generated file. I don't know what the issue is.

Here is a link to code on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/7c45c81c) and dataset on [Easyupload](https://easyupload.io/mcdjan)

Thanks in advance for any tips.

- [.html generated file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTbI0.jpg)
- [flexdashboard file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hIIa.jpg)